# How to add TextEdit, Labels and Buttons that move when Window Size is moved using PyQt?

Tags: pyqt, pyqt4, pyqt5

I am new to PyQt, but for the past days I was trying to create a GUI which has labels, TextEdit and buttons which move when the Window size is moved (minimized or enlarged), I tried doing it so but the Buttons get stuck in the top left corner while the labels and TextEdit completely don't show up on the form, Please do help . Here is a snippet of my codes

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow, QtGui.QWidget):

`   def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(50, 50, 500, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle("PTE")
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('.png'))
        self.center()

        # Adding Menu to the GUI
        quitAction = QtGui.QAction(QtGui.QIcon('exit.png'), "&Quit", self)
        quitAction.setShortcut("Ctrl+Q")  
        quitAction.setStatusTip('Exit Application')
        quitAction.triggered.connect(self.close_application)

        undoAction = QtGui.QAction(QtGui.QIcon('undo.png'), "&Undo", self)
        undoAction.setShortcut("Ctrl+Z")        
        undoAction.triggered.connect(self.close_application)

        aboutAction = QtGui.QAction("&About PTE...", self)


        self.statusBar()

        #Actual Main Menu with options
        mainMenu = self.menuBar()
        fileMenu = mainMenu.addMenu('&File')        
        fileMenu.addAction(quitAction)

        fileMenu = mainMenu.addMenu('&Edit')
        fileMenu.addAction(undoAction)

        fileMenu = mainMenu.addMenu('&Help')
        fileMenu.addAction(aboutAction)

        self.home()


    #Centering Window on the screen
    def center(self):
        gui = self.frameGeometry()
        cp = QtGui.QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
        gui.moveCenter(cp)
        self.move(gui.topLeft())


     def home(self):
         #Buttons
        qbtn = QtGui.QPushButton('Quit', self)
        qbtn.clicked.connect(self.close_application)

        rbtn = QtGui.QPushButton("Run", self)
        rbtn.clicked.connect(self.close_application)

        hbox = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        hbox.addStretch(1)
        hbox.addWidget(qbtn)
        hbox.addWidget(rbtn)

        vbox = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addStretch(1)
        vbox.addLayout(hbox)

        self.setLayout(vbox) 


        self.show()

        #Labels and TextBox 
        Intervals = QtGui.QLabel('Number of intervals (0<=20) :')
        Timesteps = QtGui.QLabel('Number of time steps (<=1000) : ')

        IntervalsEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit()
        TimestepsEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit()


        grid = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        grid.setSpacing(2)

        grid.addWidget(Intervals, 1, 0)
        grid.addWidget(IntervalsEdit, 1, 1)

        grid.addWidget(Timesteps, 2, 0)
        grid.addWidget(TimestepsEdit, 2, 1)


        self.setLayout(grid)

        self.show()

    #What to display when the app is closed    
     def close_application(self):
         #Popup message before closing the application in Binary
         choice = QtGui.QMessageBox.question(self, 'Message',"Are you sure you want to exit?", 
                                        QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes | QtGui.QMessageBox.No )

         if choice == QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes:
              print(" Until Next Time")
              sys.exit()
         else:
             pass

def run():        
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    GUI = Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

    run()
```

Comment: You are using `setLayout` twice. You can only use it once. You will need to add the `QGridLayout` to the `QHBoxLayout` (for example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey i fixed the issues with your code. In my fix, i added the `QGridLayout` to the `QHBoxLayout`. If you want the grid in another place you might need to nest both layouts in a 3rd layout.

Note that you are using `setLayout` for `grid` **and** for `vbox` when you can only set 1 layout. You also call `show()` twice, which you don't need. You also add a `QVBoxLayout` to `hbox` but do not add any widget. As it is, this is useless. If you want `hbox` and `grid` to be vertically aligned you will need to `vbox.addLayout(grid)` and `self.setLayout(vbox)` instead.

```
import sys

from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow, QtGui.QWidget):

`   def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(50, 50, 500, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle("PTE")
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('.png'))
        self.center()

        # Adding Menu to the GUI
        quitAction = QtGui.QAction(QtGui.QIcon('exit.png'), "&Quit", self)
        quitAction.setShortcut("Ctrl+Q")  
        quitAction.setStatusTip('Exit Application')
        quitAction.triggered.connect(self.close_application)

        undoAction = QtGui.QAction(QtGui.QIcon('undo.png'), "&Undo", self)
        undoAction.setShortcut("Ctrl+Z")        
        undoAction.triggered.connect(self.close_application)

        aboutAction = QtGui.QAction("&About PTE...", self)


        self.statusBar()

        #Actual Main Menu with options
        mainMenu = self.menuBar()
        fileMenu = mainMenu.addMenu('&File')        
        fileMenu.addAction(quitAction)

        fileMenu = mainMenu.addMenu('&Edit')
        fileMenu.addAction(undoAction)

        fileMenu = mainMenu.addMenu('&Help')
        fileMenu.addAction(aboutAction)

        self.home()


    #Centering Window on the screen
    def center(self):
        gui = self.frameGeometry()
        cp = QtGui.QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
        gui.moveCenter(cp)
        self.move(gui.topLeft())


     def home(self):
         #Buttons
        qbtn = QtGui.QPushButton('Quit', self)
        qbtn.clicked.connect(self.close_application)

        rbtn = QtGui.QPushButton("Run", self)
        rbtn.clicked.connect(self.close_application)

        hbox = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        hbox.addStretch(1)
        hbox.addWidget(qbtn)
        hbox.addWidget(rbtn)

        vbox = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addStretch(1)
        vbox.addLayout(hbox)



        #self.show() #this only needs to be called once

        #Labels and TextBox 
        Intervals = QtGui.QLabel('Number of intervals (0<=20) :')
        Timesteps = QtGui.QLabel('Number of time steps (<=1000) : ')

        IntervalsEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit()
        TimestepsEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit()


        grid = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        grid.setSpacing(2)

        grid.addWidget(Intervals, 1, 0)
        grid.addWidget(IntervalsEdit, 1, 1)

        grid.addWidget(Timesteps, 2, 0)
        grid.addWidget(TimestepsEdit, 2, 1)

        hbox.addLayout(grid) #this will add the grid to the horizontal layout.
        #if you want it to be vertcally aligned change this to vbox.addLayout(grid)...

        #... and this to self.setLayout(vbox)
        self.setLayout(hbox)

        self.show()

    #What to display when the app is closed    
     def close_application(self):
         #Popup message before closing the application in Binary
         choice = QtGui.QMessageBox.question(self, 'Message',"Are you sure you want to exit?", 
                                        QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes | QtGui.QMessageBox.No )

         if choice == QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes:
              print(" Until Next Time")
              sys.exit()
         else:
             pass
```

Comment: This really helps, Thanks alot, now i can add even more of the TextEdit and Labels.......Cheers

Comment: If an answer is working for you, you should accept that answer also. This improves StackOverflow as a source of questions and answers and motivates users to help other users - Welcome to StackOverflow!.